# hover Image slide up on css

Tags: css

I'm  using css3, an image that when you hover over it will slides up like [this](http://demo.theme-paradise.com/?item=semona-wp)

I find this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/as5ZU/),but I want not the box's background property.

```
    <div class="box">
  <img src=image/image.jpg>
    </div>
```

Image source is from html,not css background property

I'm just wondering if anyone can point me to a good tutorial or can help me with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I've come up with a quick example how you could do it, you can play around change values and improve it. I hope it helps.

```
 .box{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
.box img{
  width:200px;
  float:left; 
}
.box:hover img{
  margin-top:-200px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 1s;
  -moz-transition: margin 1s;
  transition: margin 1s;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/pqrnt921/1/

Comment: Thanks!! It's very helpful. I have one question, If the image's height varying, and I need slide at the end is just the height of the image. How should I do?

Comment: You'll need some javascript for it, I updated jsfiddle with jQuery solution: https://jsfiddle.net/pqrnt921/4/

Comment: Thank you!!You give me a great deal of help

Comment: Sorry ,I've one more question. In this line of code:
$(this).find('img').height()-$(this).height())
Why subtrac div's height

Comment: No problem, $(this).height() is actual height of ".box" outside element and you don't want your inside image to scroll all the way top, you want to stop it at height of the outside box, hence you need to calculate - (img height - box height) and that's exactly what this part of code does. If you're still no clear with it try removing that part -$(this).height() and you'll see that it goes all the way top. Also make sure you understand that there is minus "-" before brackets "()" so you first calculate height of image top margin then make it negative that number so image moves top.

Answer (score 1):

A pure  CSS3 slide up transition effect works better if you move the transition properties to the normal state, like this:

```
.box{ 
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
.box img{ /* Normal state */
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover img{
  margin-top:-200px;
}
```

This way, on roll Out you'll  get a nice transition to the original position.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be more universal so you don't have to worry about what image you are using (I mean, you don't have to worry about image width), I propose using `background-image`, `background-position` and `background-size`.
Here is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joe_Null/vLrab1b8/) example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4173648/joe)'s answer so, thanks Joe :).

For top-to-bottom sliding, you can simply use the following code.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://shrinktheweb.snapito.io/v2/webshot/spu-ea68c8-ogi2-3cwn3bmfojjlb56e?size=800x0&screen=1024x768&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisolpro.in');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  transition: all 2s;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

BTW, I have used `https://snapito.com/` to take fullpage screenshot of my website.